# Difference in Keras applications model lists

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, python-import, pre-trained-model

In the past I've looked for pretrained CNNs I can import from tensorflow.keras.applications from looking at the keras website list [here](https://keras.io/applications/).

I recently just noticed several more models on the [keras applications GitHub](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications), but I can't import those that aren't on the former page.

So is there any way to use these GitHub listed models with ImageNet weights in a similar way that I would import tensorflow.keras.applications models?

Comment: You should be able to import all of them. Can you give an example of a model that is not listed on the website and that you cannot import?

Comment: @sdcbr For example ResNet101

Comment: Good question, I haven't been able to import it myself. Let's hope someone else knows :)